# Return Start/End position of match in Sphinx

Tags: sphinx

Can I request star and stop position of matches in a document with sphinx?

Given say

```
select  ID from idx_1 WHERE (MATCH('@(name) "New York"'))
```

can I ask it to tell me the character position of the first Letter, 'N', in New York and the last letter, K, in New Yor'K' in the match?

Comment: What are 'N' and 'K'? You might need to define your question a bit more.

Comment: @Barryhunter Sorry I simply meant the first letter, N or New York and the last letter, K of New York. In other words start and end characters of found search term in doc. So "I live in New York City" would be 11,18

Answer (score 1):

Sphinx does not track character positions, so can't directly tell you that.

Could use `BuildExcerpts` or `SNIPPET` function, which could perhaps compare the output with the documet to deduce the position yourself.

Or there is the `PACKEDFACTORS` function, which will give you many details of the ranking calculation. In there is the WORD position of each keyword. (sphinx does track word positions, as all its matching is work (well token) based)

Comment: thanks but WORD would not help so much. For one thing I am trying to compare is two different matches include one word inside the other. In my case if i searched for 'New York' and searched for 'New' and searched for 'York' I would want to know that the New and York passes were in fact inside the New York pass. I guess I'll need to look into BuildExcerpts

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use like below while using sphinxQL

```
select * from courses where MATCH('@title PMP')  limit 0, 100;
```

Comment: Thanks though I am trying to get the position of the first 'P' and the position of the last 'P' in the document I am searching in as measured by character in the doc. So "I love PHP" is 8,10